# Fetching data from sqlite and display as listview

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to fetch data from sq lite database and display as list.
I tried different solutions given previously but no luck.

When I try to display the list, I continuously get **GC-CONCURRENT FREED**.
After sometime , I get out of memory error and the app stops responding.

**DataBaseHelper.class**

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int Database_Version = 1;
private static final String Database_Name = "remindme";
static final String Table_RemindMe = "reminders";
 static final String Key_Id = "id";
static final String Key_Title = "title";
static final String Key_Description = "description";
 static final String Key_Date = "date";
List<RemindMe> reminderList = new ArrayList<RemindMe>();


public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, Database_Name, null, Database_Version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String CREATE_REMINDME_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_RemindMe + "("
            + Key_Id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + Key_Title
            + " TEXT, " + Key_Date + " TEXT," + Key_Description + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_REMINDME_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIXTS" + Table_RemindMe);
     onCreate(db);
}

void addRemindMe(RemindMe remindme){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Key_Title, remindme.getTitle());
    values.put(Key_Description, remindme.getDescription());
    values.put(Key_Date, remindme.getDate());
    db.insert(Table_RemindMe, null, values);
    db.close();

}

public List<RemindMe> getReminder(){
    List<RemindMe> reminderList = new ArrayList<RemindMe>();
    String selectQuery = "Select * FROM " + Table_RemindMe ;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    try{

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            RemindMe reminder = new RemindMe();
            reminder.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            reminder.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            reminder.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));
            reminder.setDate(cursor.getString(3));
            reminderList.add(reminder);
        }while(cursor.moveToLast());
    }

    }
    finally{
        cursor.close();
    }
    db.close();
    return reminderList;
}
```

**List Class**

```
 DataBaseHandler db=new DataBaseHandler();
Log.d("Reading", "Reading Reminders");
 List<RemindMe> reminders= db.getReminder();

 for(RemindMe r:reminders){
 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put("Title", r.title);
  map.put("Desc", r.description);

  Items.add(map);
}


ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,Items,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,new String[]{"Iitle" , "Desc"},null);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: May be you'r working on main thread. You should use `CursorLoader`

Answer (score 1):

You need to read how databases work and how [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) are used. This looks like you tried to convert a php script line by line and besides being bad practice is very inefficient.

I can see you're new here but usually it's on you to show what you've tried to fix the problem, you can't ask for help to debug an entire project, it's just too broad to get a useful answer, so keep that in mind when you write your next question.

The problem you have at the moment is a misunderstanding of how a do...while loop works.

Basically it means "Do this once, and then keep doing it as long as this other thing is true"

So your loop goes through the first row, adds it to the list, moves to the last row (skipping the middle). Adds that to the list. Then goes to the last row again and again and again adding hundreds of the same item to the list.

All you need to change is this:

```
do {
   ...
} while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

because moveToNext will return false when there isnt a next row. The difference with [moveToLast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToLast()) is that it always returns true *unless the cursor is empty* which it never will be, because we successfully moved to first item.